# Need help with Star wars movies

Tags: star-wars

Guys i am from india none of the star wars movies have been released here but star wars episode 7 is going to be released and i think its interesting but i don't want to download all the episodes(i.e. Movies) and watch one by one, so just suggest me few so i can understand the basics and then watch upcoming additions

Comment: By "episodes", are you referring to just the movies, or are you including the TV shows (Clone Wars and Rebels)?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but as far as the new Star Wars movie is concerned, there aren't any hard and fast requirements to being allowed to watch it. You'd enjoy it more with back-story, but any decent movie will have a story of its own.

Comment: In this case it's definitely **not** OK to only watch the new ones.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: I’m not sure this is a precise duplicate — it seems to be asking which existing *Star Wars* movies (and possibly other content) need to be watched in order to fully understand *The Force Awakens*, which is different from the suggested duplicate which asks which viewing order is best for the existing films taken on their own. (And as far as I know, that’s unanswerable, because no-one outside of those working on the movie knows what’s going to be in it yet.)

Comment: And just so you know http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_shot_first

Comment: If you're going to only watch *some* of the movies, I'd suggest only watching 4-6. **However** since we don't know the actual plot of Ep 7, we have no guarantee that you'll know everything necessary just from watching *some* of the original movies.

Comment: Seriously, Just watch all of them. There's only 6.

Answer (score 1):

There'll be many opinions regarding this, but this question basically boils down to one decision: **Watch episode 1-3 or skip them.**

Many people disliked episodes 1-3 simply due to a different tone and a far lighter approach (also due to *Jar-Jar Binks* and the predetermination of episode 3's end). The classic trilogy (now episodes 4-6) depicts a far darker setting where there's always that evil empire, just striving for dominating or defeating the rebel alliance.

In the prequels, it's far less obvious and while there are clearly bad guys, they're (at the beginning) not as evident or allmighty.

- For the bare minimum, you should watch the classic trilogy (i.e. episodes 4 through 6).
- If you want to see it all, watch all six episodes in numerical order.
- If you'd like to include the animated series *Clone Wars*, then watch the first two movies, followed by the series, followed by the remaining four movies.

I've yet to see *Rebels*, so I'm not sure how/where to put those (probably past the other movies).

Comment: “watch all six episodes in numerical order” — really? As in *Phantom*, *Clones*, *Sith*, *New Hope*, *Empire*, *Return*? Not order of release?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes. They tell you a story in chronological (in-universe) order. If you watch them in the order they've been made, you'll get a flashback through episodes 1-3. It's a bit "hen and egg", but this way episode 3 will be a lot more interesting. You'll see episodes 4-6 in a bit different way, but if you want to see them all, I'd recommend this order. Keep in mind that there are still about twenty years between episodes three and four, so the story won't just continue straight away, yet many things in the original trilogy refer back to the prequels.

Comment: sure, but it won’t tell you the story in the order that the filmmakers told it. Do you think everyone who saw the movies in theatres in the day of release experienced them in a less-enjoyable order that people who watch in your suggested order?

Comment: In all honesty, no one can re-live A New Hope as it was intended in '77. It was a renaissance, it even breathed life back into Star Trek. Darth Vader, unveiled for the first time to the viewer as Episode 4 intended. We were meant to know about 4 through 6 before 1-3 came out, 4 was supposed to be new and it's presentation is as such. To cram any of 1-3 into the original trilogy is essentially the Machete Order.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite IMO it's a bit about how you want to experience the story. By watching 1-3 first, you'll get a far more interesting episode 3 at the cost of some of the revelations of episodes 5 and 6 (some will just switch to another perspective). If you watch 4-6 first, you'll learn about characters the "original way", yet episode 3 will appear even weaker given the known ending (at least for me it felt like the worst and most boring of the newer movies).

Comment: @Mario: true. I think you’d be sacrificing some enjoyability of the superior original trilogy just to make the end of *Sith* more interesting, and any effort spent helping the prequel trilogy look better offends my bitter inner nerd. Interesting perspective though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the real Stars Wars' watching experience, then you should watch first the episodes 4 through 6.  Later, when you have some time lose and you don't know what else to do, then you can watch the episodes 1 to 3.

Even if you plan to watch the full serie 1 to 6 in a single swoop, you should begin with the episode 4 to 6 first; as this in my opinion the only way to have the real experience because they have been made in that order and therefore, you will be able to see the evolution of the serie as made by the directors.

If you look first at the episodes 1 to 3, non only many surprise elements of the classic trilogy will be spoiled but chance are that you will get tired of some of its more interesting features before even beginning to watch the real deal.  In short, you can consider watching these three episodes first as a long, big spoiler for the next three.

As for the animated series, watch them last, if you care.